# Why doesn't a pointer to derived and a pointer to base point to the same address if abstract classes are involved?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, virtual

I came across a problem which can be reduced to the following example:

```
#include "iostream"

struct A {
    char a;
};
struct B : A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
struct C : B {
    void f() override {}
};

void f(A* fpa) {
    std::cout << fpa << '\n' << reinterpret_cast<C*>(fpa) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    C c {};
    A* pa {&c};
    std::cout << &c << '\n' << pa << '\n' << reinterpret_cast<C*>(pa) << std::endl;
    f(&c);
}
```

Neither `pa` nor `fpa` keep pointing to the address of `c`, although both are being initialized with `&c`. All addresses printed after that of `&c` directly are offset by +8 (tested with g++ and clang++). Removing either A::a or B::f() and C::f() or initializing `pa` and `fpa` with `reinterpret_cast<A*>(&c)` instead of just `&c` fixes the addresses.

But why do I have to do that? Shouldn't any `A*` be able to hold the address to any `A`, `B`, or `C` in this case since all inheritance is public? Why does the value change implicitly? And are there warning flags I can pass to g++ or clang++ that warn about this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or initializing pa and fpa with `reinterpret_cast<A*>(&c)` instead of just `&c` fixes the addresses.

That doesn't "fix" the address. That *breaks* the address. It yields an invalid pointer.

> But why do I have to do that?

You don't have to do that. The offset address is the correct address of the base sub object.

> Why doesn't a pointer to derived and a pointer to base point to the same address if abstract classes are involved?

Because there is something stored in the object before the base sub object.

> Shouldn't any A* be able to hold the address to any A, B, or C

No. The address of a valid pointer to A is always the address of an A object. If the dynamic type is derived, then that A object is a base sub object. The base can be stored at an offset from the beginning of the derived class.

> since all inheritance is public

Accessibility of the Inheritance is irrelevant in this regard.

> And are there warning flags I can pass to g++ or clang++ that warn about this kind of behavior?

I highly doubt that there would be. I also don't see why you'd want a warning in such case.

Comment: A further possible solution I stumbled upon is adding a virtual destructor to `A`. That way all printed addresses are the same. Is that breaking things as well?

I also realized that this might have been an XY problem because the actual program segfaulted at an attempted cast from (the equivalent of) `A` to `B` within a function of `B` calling another function of `B`. Tracing the bug I noticed the value of the passed pointer changed and assumed that was the bug and everything afterward UB because I haven't noticed that behavior before.

Comment: @Rawwrptor Adding a virtual destructor won't make the broken reinterpret cast correct. What it does achieve is make deleting a derived object through a pointer to `A` well defined.

Comment: Adding a virtual destructor to `A` results in the same value being printed for `&c` and `pa` without any casting. I added the reinterpret casts to the example to show that they also didn't result in the desired outcome and initializing `pa` and `fpa` with `reinterpret_cast<A*>(&c)` was a solution I came up with that seemed right at first until you told me it's wrong, so I discarded it. My question now is: with the virtual destructor in `A`, will `&c`, `pa` and `fpa` in the above code always result in the same value being printed for them? No matter how I extend `A`, `B`, and `C`?

Comment: @Rawwrptor No, adding the virtual destructor does not give you a guarantee that the base sub object would share the same address as the derived instance.

Comment: Or rather, with a virtual destructor in `A` and an additional member `A*` in `A`, can I safely reinterpret cast that member in `B` to a `B*` if I know that it's actually holding a `C*`?

Comment: @Rawwrptor No. Such reinterpretation will not be safe. static_cast will be safe if you know the dynamic type. Regardless of the virtuality of the destructor of A. static_cast takes the type system into consideration and knows the offsets of base class sub objects in their derived objects.

Comment: Nice! That seems to work. I don't know where I have picked that up, but I always assumed reinterpret_cast was for pointers and static_cast for non-pointer values. Looks like I might have some cleanup to do. Thank you!

Comment: @Rawwrptor reinterpret_cast is for when you are bypassing the type system. It's quite rare to need it, and you need to know subtle details of the language rules to not make a mistake with it.